# Multiple serverless files sharing the same api gateway

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I am using serverless framework to build a REST API. I have reached the 200 limit stack size and read about the multiple approaches to circumvent it. The most common approach is to split the stacks in a "microservices fashion", where each stack handles a particular set of resources that make sense together.

Because of how serverless works each of those services would create a new api gateway for itself and then, as explained in this [blog post](https://serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-multiple-services/), a shared domain can be setup between them so all endpoints can be accessed through the same base url.

Even though this is a valid solution I would really like to be able to work with a single API gateway resource shared between the different stacks, so I don't have to decide upfront a separation of concerns between the different components of my api. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature has been recently added to serverless. Documentation is available [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#share-api-gateway-and-api-resources).

Essentially the apiGateway to be used in a serverless file can be configured through a config option inside "providers".

```
provider: 
  ...
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: xxxxxxxxxx # REST API resource ID. Default is generated by the framework
    restApiRootResourceId: xxxxxxxxxx # Root resource, represent as / path
```

This feature was introduced by this [pull request](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/4247) and is available from serverless version 1.26.