# How to get same host on api gateway aws using serverless fraemwork in different service

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have to 2 service. I want to deploy it and get the same aws host.
1. This is first configuration serverless.yml

```
service: test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: prod
  region: ap-southeast-1

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  bilangangenap:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: test/satu
          method: post
    timeout: 120
```

2. This is second configuration serverless.yml

```
service: test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: prod
  region: ap-southeast-1

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
    bilanganganjil:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: test/dua
          method: post
    timeout: 120
```

When I deploy first service, I got end point :
https://abcdefgh.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test/satu

And when I deploy second service, I got end point :
https://abcdefgh.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/test/dua

But when I deploy second service, the first service will be deleted.
I want to use same host like : https://abcdefgh.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com with different end point.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? If you deploy two services (with different names - test and test2) you'll get two different endpoints domains - one won't overwrite the other. That said, I believe this question is otherwise a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773229/multiple-serverless-files-sharing-the-same-api-gateway

Comment: Sorry. I'm wrong explain my question. I mean with same service name.